# How to retrieve source code of mathchar?

Tags: math-mode, sourcecode

I'm looking for source code of mathchar ∈, latex `\in`. I want to modify it for my own use.

Comment: `\in` is usually defined with (something that boils down to) `\mathchardef\in="3232`.  What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: if you mean you want the source of the actual letter shape you need to access the font you are using (either metafont or the actual font which is almost certainly type1 or opentype these days) Glyph design is not a tex question.

Comment: How do you want to modify it?  For certain types of modifications, standard or otherwise simple ways may present themselves

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems the \in character contains a space before and after itself. I want to remove those spaces.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes tagging you too since I don't know if you'll be notified without it.

Comment: `\in` is a binary relation so spaced like = use `{\in}` to see it as a normal character with no relation space.

Answer (score 3):

Based on comments ("*It seems the \in character contains a space before and after itself. I want to remove those spaces.*"), the OP wishes to disable the spacing around `\in`.  That can be done temporarily (preferred) or permanently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a \in b$ normal behavior

$a{\in}b$ temporarily disable mathrel in

\let\svin\in
\def\in{\mathord{\svin}}

$a\in b$ permanently disable mathrel in
\end{document}
```

[image]